# Отправка двух переменных ajax методом в обработчик

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, что делаю не так:

Вот сам код

```
var myData = 'content_txt=' + $("#blog_text").val();
var myDatat = 'content_title=' + $("#blog_title").val();
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "d1b6.php",
    dataType: "text",
    data: myData,
});
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы отсылалось две переменные myData и myDatat? Заранее спасибо!

**Ps** на данный момент отправляется только myData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сериализовать данные формы ([.serialize()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83) / [.serializeArray()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2)), а можно просто, вот таким способом:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    /* прочие опции */
    data:{content_txt: $("#blog_text").val(), content_title: $("#blog_title").val()}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ну как вариант запихнуть переменные в массив или сделать объект с свойствами myData,myDatat и отправить уже их